# Print value from find command in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have following playbook:

```
  - name: Find files
    find:
     paths: "{{ ARCHIVE }}"
     patterns: "{{ item }}_*"
     file_type: directory
    register: files_matched
    with_items: "{{ bucket_with_items }}"

#  - debug:
#     var: files_matched

  - name: Remove directories
    file:
     path: "{{ item.files.path }}"
     state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_matched.results }}"
```

But when i execute this, i get following error messages:

```
fatal: [uwd-sschbn-01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'path'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/couchbase.yml': line 42, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Remove directories\n
```

My situation is, i want to delete folders which are stored in 'files_matched' register module. But before that i just wanted to see what is being stored in files_matched  variable. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you added a `with_items`, the `files_matched` got to this format:

```
  "files_matched": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "changed": false, 
                "examined": 14, 
                "failed": false, 
                "files": [
                    {
                        "atime": 1526147209.0100496, 
                        "ctime": 1526147209.0100496, 
                        "dev": 43, 
                        "gid": 0,
```

you will notice there is `files_matched.results` now, that has a list of "results" that contain the `files` var you are looking for.

you can use this `debug` task to print the results of your previous task:

```
  - debug: 
      msg: " value is  {{ item.files }} "
    with_items:
      - "{{ files_matched.results }}"
```

**EDIT**

the above will display you the results from the registered variable of the previous task. to delete files/directories you will need to parse the `files_matched.results` in a `set_fact` task to convert to a list, and then in another loop, process them (delete them in your case).

example:

```
  - name: get results in list
    set_fact:
      results_list: "{{ files_matched.results | map(attribute='files') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

  - name: print results
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ results_list }}"
```

Comment: Ok I have tried with_itmes in debug in my playbook.
Not sure why i'm getting "u" in front of every field.

For example i'm getting:
 u'path': u'/opt/couchbase/backup/ansible/ranjit-test2_20180506', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1526220040.8015256,

Comment: This shouldn't worry you, its how Ansible prints it, the variable itself doesnt have those 'u'.

Comment: but i'm not getting the files. it shows following:

    "msg": "value is  [{u'uid': 0, u'woth': False, u'mtime': 1526224917.1981974, u'inode': 8399, u'isgid': False, u'size': 4096, u'roth': False, u'isuid': False, u'isreg': False, u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr':  u'issock': False, u'rgrp': True, u'path': u'/opt/couchbase/backup/ansible/ranjit-test2_20180506', u'xusr': True, u'atime': 1526224915.2121181, u'isdir': True, u'ctime': 1526224917.1981974, u'wgrp': True, u'xgrp': True, u'dev': 2049, u'isblk': False, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0770', u'islnk': False}]"
}

Comment: Have used following:
  - debug:
     msg: "value is  {{ item.files }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ files_matched.results }}"

Comment: then check the pattern you are using to find files

Comment: but i see my searched directory/file under the json output.

u'path': u'/opt/couchbase/backup/ansible/ranjit-test2_20180506',

Comment: lets see the `files_matched` variable with the results you got then. please add it to the question: use `var` and not `msg` please

Comment: I changed it to following code but it doesn't work, sorry i'm a newbie to ansible

  - debug:
     var: "value is  {{ item.files }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ files_matched.results }}"

Comment: plz use:  `- debug: var: files_matched` (in seperate lines as it should be)

Comment: I got following output, (removed extra files)
ok: [uwd-sschbn-01] => {
    "files_matched": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "examined": 7,
                "files": [
                    {
                        "atime": 1526230188.581521,
                        "ctime": 1526140069.4248221,
                        "path": "/opt/couchbase/backup/ansible/ranjit-test_201805067",
                        "uid": 0,
                    },

Comment: Used following code as suggested by you to inspect the variable

  - debug:
     var: files_matched

Comment: so u need the value stored in the `path` attribute of the `files`, with value: `/opt/couchbase/backup/ansible/ranjit-test_201805067` ?

Comment: yes, so that i can delete this directory:
Basically i want to use following:

  - name: Remove directories
    file:
     path: "{{ item.files }}"
     state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_matched.results }}"

Comment: my answer was on helping with the `debug` task that you could not make it display results due to the `with_items` loop. to delete files you will have to use in a loop the `item.files.path`, used `with_items` as in the `debug` example i wrote in the answer

Comment: oh ok, sorry i should have also shared the delete. 
But even after using the [ item.files.path ] , I see error like following:
fatal: [uwd-sschbn-01]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'path'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/abc.yml': line 42, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending

Comment: cant continue from comments. i suggest you update the question, add the code with the find and delete directories steps, so we can find the problem.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: did you have a chance to look at my updated question and the error stack that i placed?

Comment: updated the answer, please check

Comment: That worked..... Thanks a lot!
But initially i faced error and then i upgrade the jinja2  to 2.7  from 2.6 to resolve error